# Read from Text File and Save to Two or Three Variables

Tags: c++, input

Currently, I have a program that reads from a text input file that is expected to be in the format:

```
add A B
add A C
add B D
breadth A
depth A
remove A B
add B A
breadth B
depth B
```

However, I wrote my program to be:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv){

        ifstream fin(argv[1]);

        string cmnd;
        char v1, v2;


        while (fin >> cmnd >> v1 >> v2){

                     if (cmnd == "add"){
                             //do something
                     }

                     if (cmnd == "remove"){
                             //do something
                     }

                     if (cmnd == "breadth"){
                             //do something
                     }

                     if (cmnd == "depth"){
                             //do something
                     }
         }
```

Of course, it ends when it reaches a line in the text file with just two variable, such as "breadth A" or "depth A". Someone had quickly suggested in-person to me that I could just addd a second nested while loop for readth and depth to fix this but I didn't follow. The variables will only ever be two or three. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to get a work around as follows:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv){

          ifstream fin(argv[1]);

          string cmnd;
          char v1, v2;

          while (fin >> cmnd){

                if (cmnd == "add"){
                    (fin >> v1 >> v2);
                     //do something
                }

                if (cmnd == "breadth"){
                    (fin >> v1); 
                    //etc...
                 }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with whitespace. Remember that newlines are also whitespace. To see what is going wrong, convert all of your newlines to spaces and walk through the program. At the point that you are reading `breadth A` your variables will contain the following:

```
cmnd="breadth"
v1='A'
v2='d' // from depth
```

This is a framing error. Since you have optional input terminated with newlines, you might look at `istream::getline()`.